# IntelliJ: Specifying different groovyc version for source and test within same module

Tags: java, groovy, intellij-idea, ivy, spock

I am using `IntelliJ 11.1.3`, `IvyIDEA Plugin for IntelliJ`, `Spock 0.5` (which depends on `Groovy 1.8.4`), and `Groovy 1.5.6`.

I have an IntelliJ module that follows [Maven Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).  The output is a WAR file.

When doing a build of this module in IntelliJ, is there any way that I can tell IntelliJ to use the following:

- `Groovy 1.5.6` to compile `src/main/groovy`
- `Groovy 1.8.4` to compile `src/test/groovy`

I need to do this because the actual application code needs to be compiled against `Groovy 1.5.6` (long story short: the WAR that is generated is deployed with an EAR that must stay on `Groovy 1.5.6` for now).

The Test directory, of course, does not get deployed with the WAR.  The Test directory contains Spock Tests.  I am using Spock 0.5, which requires `Groovy 1.8.x`

**ivy.xml**

```
<dependency conf="compile->default" name="groovy-all" 
    org="org.codehaus.groovy" rev="1.5.6"/>

<dependency conf="test->default" name="groovy-all" 
    org="org.codehaus.groovy" rev="1.8.4"/>
<dependency conf="test->default" name="spock-core" 
    org="org.spockframework" rev="0.5-groovy-1.8"/>
```

I need to be able to run tests from IntelliJ.  If I build from IntelliJ and attempt to run a Spock Test, I get the following:

```
org.spockframework.runtime.InvalidSpecException: 
Specification 'org.myorg.test.ProcessCaseTest' was not compiled properly 
(Spock AST transform was not run); try to do a clean build
at org.spockframework.runtime.SpecUtil.checkIsSpec(SpecUtil.java:53)
```

If I remove this line:

```
<dependency conf="compile->default" name="groovy-all" 
    org="org.codehaus.groovy" rev="1.5.6"/>
```

then I can build and run Spock Tests, but I lose Groovy from my module.

I think what I need to do is tell IntelliJ to use one version of Groovy to compile the application code and another version of Groovy to compile the tests, but I have not been able to find a way to do this.

I would be extremely grateful for any help or insight that anyone could provide.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDEA follows the Maven dependency model where `compile` dependencies automatically make it to the `test` class path. What you can try is to reorder dependencies in the IDEA module so that Groovy 1.8 (which should have scope `test`) comes before Groovy 1.5 (which should have scope `compile`). Anyway, it's a hairy affair.

PS: I recommend to use Spock 0.6.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, Peter!  You're right, it is hairy.  I did as you suggested in reordering the dependencies in our IDEA module and it worked.  I love Spock, it's a great testing framework that feels very natural ... I'll look into Spock 0.6 and probably start using that once I understand what has changed since 0.5.